# Remove WARNING "A docBase inside the host appBase has been specified" from tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, startup, c3p0

I have a application with context.xml inside server conf like this 'conf/Catalina/localhost'.

It's configure my JNDI perfectly, but I'm getting this warning on startup:

```
24-Nov-2017 13:46:59.352 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase /tomcat8/prod/webapps/ROOT inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
```

I know that something is duplicated inside my application aboult my context.xml, but I don't know where to look and remove it.

I already removed context.xml from 'webapps/ROOT/META-INF'

Any help is welcome.